# What does %r mean in kernel printf formats?

Tags: c, kernel, printf, freebsd

In several places in the kernel source code I could find this used:

One example is

```
if (console_sc != NULL && console_sc->vtermid == sc->vtermid) {
        sc->outseqno = console_sc->outseqno;
        console_sc = sc;
        sprintf(uart_phyp_consdev.cn_name, "ttyu%r", unit);
        tty_init_console(sc->tp, 0);
}
```

Another example is:

```
        if (!(vw->vw_flags & VWF_READY)) {
                callout_init(&vw->vw_proc_dead_timer, 0);
                terminal_maketty(vw->vw_terminal, "v%r", VT_UNIT(vw));
                vw->vw_flags |= VWF_READY;
                if (vw->vw_flags & VWF_CONSOLE) {
                        /* For existing console window. */
                        EVENTHANDLER_REGISTER(shutdown_pre_sync,
                            vt_window_switch, vw, SHUTDOWN_PRI_DEFAULT);
                }
        }
```

but if I look in the sprintf man page I can not find any reference to the 'r' format specifier.

What does it do and where is it documented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out the [sprintf](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-3.3/sprintf.9) man page. it is  stated :

> %r    Displays an integer using the current DDB radix.  This
>   non-standard
>              interpretation of %r is only available to db_printf().

[here](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ddb&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD%206.0-RELEASE) are more informations about DDB.